# Displaying only javascript values in select tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I am having one select tag

```
<select id="pname">
    <option>saome data</option>
</select>
```

After javascript function run i want to display only javascript values in select tag, i tried this as below

```
    <script>
  function xyz() {

    $.ajax({
      url: 'abc.php',
      type: "get",
      cache: false,
      data: {
        cat: $('#xyzn').val()
      },
      success: function(response) {
        var myObject = JSON.parse(response);


        $('#pname').val(myObject.details[3]);
      }
    })

  }
</script>
```

like this i am using javascript for display only javascript value but its not working.
please help in this.

Comment: Unless your myObject.details[3] items are wrapped in the option tag then the data will not be displayed.

Comment: if your query was solved please accept one of the answers that helped you and upvote the one that were useful, this's how SO works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `myObject.details[3]` is an array you can loop over it and append your values there.

```
var myObject = JSON.parse(response);
myObject.details[3].forEach(function (val) {
    $('#pname').append($('<option>',
        {
            value: val,
            text: val
        }));
});
```

Else just append like the following.

```
$('#pname').append($('<option>', {
    value: myObject.details[3],
    text: myObject.details[3]
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can append the option tags using `jQuery`.

try this

```
$('#pname').append("<option>"+myObject.details[3]+"</option>")
```

hope it works

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your questions completely but I think you want to make a option for data obtained from that file. And you want to remove other options. This can done by:

```
$('#pname').html("<option>" + myObject.details[3] + "</option>");
```

if you want to **keep the existing data**, use this:

```
$('#pname').append("<option>" + myObject.details[3] + "</option>");
```